# How to render utf8 encoded blob in VueJS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, vue.js, blob

I am trying to convert a binary blob which is fetched from database into an image which I can render with an `<img>`-Tag.

In my Laravel backend I return the blob/data like this:

```
$user = User::find($id);

$user->photo = utf8_encode($user->photo); // $user->photo is saved as blob in MySQL database

return $user;
```

The reason why I use `utf8_encode` is that the data is returned as JSON.

In VueJS I did try the following to render the image:

```
<input type="file" @change="onFileSelect">
<img :src="setImage(userdata.photo)">

setImage(image) {
    let objurl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([image]));

    return objurl;
}

onFileSelect(e) {
    this.userdata.photo = e.target.files[0];
}
```

If I select a file in `input` the image is rendered accordingly. But when I fetch my data from server it should load the saved image.

If I `console.log(image)` inside the `setImage(image)` method after the server request I get the following output:

> PNG
>
> IHDRu<ÔFiCCPICC ProfileHWXSÉ[RIh¤ÞD)Ò¥Ð"Hl$PBL"vdQÁµØÐUE×ÈZ±E±÷e],ØPyºú½÷¾w¾ïÜûçÌÿÌ½w­®Dj+ÎÆ3Ç¥¤2I0t.O&aÅÆF(÷Ê»ëQÜ¯8+¸~ÿ¯¢ÃÈx ±§óe¼\÷ð$Ò|ÞÐn55_¢À ÖÂ!(p¦
>   (pº
>   W*}âØïLãr¥h6C;³ y4oBì"æÄh!à ¹|# §ÀÐØ§ÇùÎôAN.7s«jQ
>   9D$äp§ýíøß#a&FÄ)j}»©À4»ÅéÑ1ëBüAÄWúCRòD?jÂ±aÏÄ.|nH$Ä&s¢£ÔöôQb¸BÐBQ>'A=w@¯æ¬æÅÅà)¥ÛÀ*ã*üOÈ³YjþBgÿm0!Y3F-%EC¬  ±,;>RåY ÙÑ>Ry"k}âð`?6)C§öæÊêÅEh5®Ê&D¨yvð¸Êü
>   !nY<Ù¸¨ZøPUíØ%8Q]/Ö!ÉSÏ}-ÉUûãTAN¸Ân ±¬ ^=ÈRÅGKòcTyâéYÜÑ±ª|ðBØ 0j:ÈY@ÔÖÝÔ
>   ©FÂHA&gµe`F²rD¯ñ üÈç+G Ú¿ZUWg¡-PÎÈO Î þ+g£%ÇÐ"ú):æU1ö³-Qj|©5àI%#aDÜÀýð(x
>   ê{ã>Ù~ó'bG°fìvHWÑcå*§Ì'ò~ÇUÇTtRæRïÒåòY5/(T¼;O2M*Êæ3YðÍ/rÄ¼áÃn.®ð­­ø¨^S=ßÄHçm|nGi÷÷÷øf@ãP¨ÝßlöÐ¯pf>O.-PÙpÅ¿PZð2fÀ

If I pass that stuff to my `setImage()` method I do not get any error. The blob URL is created but the `<img>` Tag just shows an "empty" image.
And so on. Is there a way how I can convert this utf8_encoded blob into something useful?

Comment: Why do you store an image as blob in DB?

Comment: @commonsense That's the way I would like to handle my upload. I don't want to create a tmp folder or something where I save each upload.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, so had to post as an answer. I will remove if needed.

You could use a library to handle blob parsing on the front-end.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob-util

That library has built in ES module support, so should work out-of-the-box with Vue.